# EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile. In a Docker dev-environment

Tags: docker, beta

Trying to build a github repo locally using the docker dev environment and getting an EPERM error.

`➤ YN0001: │ Error: esbuild-linux-arm64@npm:0.14.54: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/root/.yarn/berry/cache/esbuild-linux-arm64-npm-0.14.54-494e5f1b94-8.zip' -> '/com.docker.devenvironments.code/.yarn/cache/esbuild-linux-arm64-npm-0.14.54-494e5f1b94-8.zip-5d136c97b7bea2c4.tmp'`

Tried updating docker and changing the node versions to higher minor versions other than that mentioned in the package.json(16.13).
Running through sudo doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Gvie us more info,which OS,which npm?

Comment: It's yarn 3.3.0, node v16.13.2 (there's npm too which is 5.3 but running through yarn) on a docker dev-environment running on macOs ventura

Comment: i copied the ssh of a github repo and ran it in the docker dev-environment. It created a environment for me but when I go to run the "make up"(build the repo) I run into the EPERM error above. I'm new to docker so not sure how to go about it honestly